# Rails: Is there a way of having only one contact form for a site that generates different HTML emails depending on what page it came from?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, actionmailer

I'm building a rails app at the moment and am wondering if there is a way of simplifying the contact form process. Initially I was going to build a contact form for the home page, and a contact form for a 'become a partner' page. Each with their own controllers and html emails. However it got me wondering if there is a way of having only the one contact form and controller that generates the appropriate html email depending on which page it was submitted on? Basically I'd like the client to get an email with either, 'new message from home page' or 'new message from become a partner page'.

I'm sure there's a way but I'm having difficulty working out the relationship.

Thanks

---

Thanks @cristiano for your replies, really appreciate it. I don't suppose you could lay it out for me could you? I'm just battling a little at the moment. Below are my files:

contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
        @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

        if @contact.save
            flash[:success] = "Message Sent!"
            redirect_to new_contact_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "Error occurred"
            redirect_to new_contact_path
        end
    end

    private
        def contact_params
            params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :comments)
        end
end
```

---

contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true

    after_create :send_email

    private
        def send_email
            ContactMailer.contact_email(self).deliver
        end
end
```

---

contact_mailer.rb

```
class ContactMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default to: 'justin@socialplayground.com.au'

    def contact_email(contact)
        @contact = contact

        mail(from: @contact.email, subject: 'Contact Form Message').deliver
    end

end
```

---

contact_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>New message from RuNpiXelruN's Contact Form!, from <%= "#{@contact.name}, #{@contact.email}" %></p>
        </br>
        <p><%= @contact.name %></p>
        <p><%= @contact.phone %></p>
        <p><%= @contact.comments %></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

It'd be in the subject of contact mailer where'd id want it to say from home page or from partner sign-up page etc

Sorry, but thanks again

Justin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a partial `_form.html.erb` and call it wherever you want.

Inside your controller you can check from where request came by calling `request.original_url`.

Thus your `home.html.erb` could be

```
<HTML for home page>
<%= render 'form' %>
<more HTML for home page>
```

Your `become_a_partner.html.erb` could be

```
<HTML for partner page>
<%= render 'form' %>
<more HTML for partner page>
```

Your `_form.html.erb` could be

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :nome %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.text_area :message %>
<% end %>
```

And finally you can check from where request came so that you can set proper message.

Comment: @cristiano_alencar thanks for the reply Cristiano! I never knew about the request.... methods, there's so many of them, that's really useful. I've had a little read of the docs but just wanted to check with you, that basically i'd have a conditional in my controller that if request.original_url = http://.... then send this html email, else this, yes?

Comment: If your emails only differ by message, you could set a @message variable so that you could pass it to your ActionMailer. If your emails are totally different to each other, so you should use different emails defining different methods in your ActionMailer so that you'd fire different emails.

Comment: Hi @cristiano_alencar, please see my edit above. Thanks again.

Comment: You're on the right way. Define your contact_email with a second parameter: page. So you can use that page message to send from where contact was made.

Comment: Ohh I'm so sorry to keep asking, but would you be able to write a solution or something close to it? I've never done this before and just completely lost. Sorry Cristiano, thanks for the reply again though.